# FritzBox connection only between wlan devices

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, routing, raspberry-pi

I have a really weird problem.

I can't connect to my raspberry pi via WLAN when I try it from my PC via Ethernet. When I use WLAN on my PC and try the same it works.

The Pi itself works fine, has an IP, can connect to the internet. Nothing weird.

Address resolution seems to work because tracert reveals it knows the hostname when using it on the ip.

My router is a FritzBox 7390 with the newest software.
I'm clueless

Comment: You mean, your PC is connected to the Fritzbox via Ethernet, your RaspPi is connected to the Fritzbox via WLAN, and they can't see each other? Hostname resolution means nothing, that's done by the Fritzbox. What happens if they ping each other, from both sides? What's the output of `arp` on each?

Comment: You enabled "Die unten angezeigten aktiven WLAN-Geräte dürfen untereinander kommunizieren"?

Comment: yes thats what i mean. can't get to the pi atm, but the arp on the pc to the pi reveals a mac address together with the IP of the pi.

Comment: @dirkt yeah its enabled. Also all new device are allowed to aswell

Comment: Does it work from the RaspPi to the PC? Possibly the Fritzbox doesn't bridge LAN and WLAN. Though Ithink I remember I tried that at some stage with my 7490, and it worked, but maybe I remember wrongly.

Comment: Okay ping from the pi to the pc doesn't work aswell. Arp table only reveals wlan devices as far as I can see.

Comment: Did you configure a guest WLAN? This would isolate LAN from WLAN. A quick check might be whether the router's config UI can be reached from WLAN.

Comment: Just tried it again with my 7490, and it works fine (Laptop on LAN, main PC on WLAN). So it must be some configuration problem somewhere.

Comment: I did not configure a guest WLAN. Still i have no idea where the configuration problem is