# Can't access local devices connected to Fritz!Box Via Wireless

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wifi-configuration, fritzbox

I am using a FritzBox 7530 router and can't access devices connected via wireless.
For example, I have a server and a Smart TV; both are connected via WIFI alongside other devices such as Raspberry Pi and mobile phones. I can't reach any of them.

Only LAN-connected devices can talk to each other. However, what is confusing is that my PC can discover all other devices. But I can't communicate with them; the same goes for my phone.

I even tried to contact AVM (Fritzbox manufacturer), but they did not know what the issue was and started telling me random stuff, such as turning the Router off and on again, even tho I explained the case with every tiny detail.

**The network looks like this:**

- My PC
- Server
- TV
- Raspberry PI
- Mobile Phone 1
- Mobile Phone 2

I installed [Fing](https://www.fing.com/) on my phone, and as mentioned, I saw all other devices but couldn't ping or connect to them.

**Troubleshooting steps I took:**

- I connected the server and my PC to the Phone Hotspot, and it worked as it should.
- I reset the Router to the Factory setting
- I made sure that the option "Active wireless devices may communicate with each other" was on; I even turned it off and on again
- Once the "Active wireless devices may communicate with each other" option is turned off, my PC or phone can't see the other devices in the network anymore.
- The guest Network is Off and has never been activated since the reset of the Router.
- The DHCP is on; I even tried to switch it to manual and assign the IP manually, but it did not work either.
- I tried to switch all related or may-seem-related options on and off.

My question/problem is not the first of this type but is a common issue with FritzBox routers, as mentioned in those questions:
[fritzbox connection only between WLAN devices](https://superuser.com/questions/1167966/fritzbox-connection-only-between-wlan-devices)
[Can't access local devices connected to Fritz!Box](https://superuser.com/questions/1805371/cant-access-local-devices-connected-to-fritzbox)

**Does anyone know what the issue could be?**

Comment: It does seem to be a common problem. Make sure you've updated it after doing a factory reset? One issue seems to be that LAN ports can be in guest mode separately (or maybe just port 4?). I also see that changes to guest status may not take effect until rebooting and getting a new IP. It makes sense that something is stuck in guest mode, because direct communication is blocked but broadcast/discovery is allowed (common in home routers for some reason). See: https://en.avm.de/service/knowledge-base/dok/FRITZ-Box-7530/549_Shared-files-and-printers-on-a-computer-are-not-visible-in-home-network/

Comment: @Cpt.Whale That is possible, but as I said above, I reset the router and never activated the guest mode afterward. Also, the issue is that the WLAN-connected devices can't communicate with each other. The LAN-connected devices have no issues

Comment: Does it have system logs you could check? The next level of troubleshooting could be to do a packet capture on two devices and the router if possible. Then narrow down whether traffic fails in one direction (like a device receives, but the reply fails), or only specific kinds of traffic fail? It's still probably something their support will have to fix since you've already tried the "Active wireless devices may communicate with each other" options

Comment: When using Fing, please post the IP address (and any other details you can find on it) on one wifi and one wired connection.  I have had this problem on Unify, and netgear in the past, and others have had them on other routers/switches.  For me, it started working all of a sudden.  Also check the settings on the router which may separate them.